# how can i store rows that repeat on a certain value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with about 3m rows, and i want to know which id's have more than one unique value for a column lets call company_id. (i dont want to remove them, i need to identify these rows for analysis)

### Table

| id | company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 3 | 33 |

in this example it would store the id's 1 and 3 because they have two different unique values for company_id. But it wouldnt store the id 2 because it has only one unique value for company_id (11)

I dont want to know how many are labeled in each company_id, i just need their id or index. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `id`, then calculate `nunique` aggregate for `company_id` for each groups:

```py
>>> df.groupby('id')['company_id'].agg('nunique')
id
1    2
2    1
3    2
Name: company_id, dtype: int64
```